# Pass jQuery serializeArray form to WCF

Tags: jquery, json, wcf

I am looking to pass a serializeArray form, essentially:

```
$.each($('#myform').serializeArray(), function () {
    json[this.name] = this.value;
});
var param = "{\"form\":" + JSON.stringify(json) + "}";
```

to a WCF service. My goal is to pass `param` to a WCF method and them parse everything inside of param, or what was passed. I would be tough to create a class of object type because the form can change. Any help with this is great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd check out [json.org](http://json.org/) for a parser.  I use Json.NET

[Here](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/) is an example of what I think you are talking about:

```
string json = @"{
   'CPU': 'Intel',
   'PSU': '500W',
   'Drives': [
     'DVD read/writer'
     /*(broken)*/,
     '500 gigabyte hard drive',
     '200 gigabype hard drive'
   ]
}";

JsonTextReader reader = new JsonTextReader(new StringReader(json));
while (reader.Read())
{
  if (reader.Value != null)
    Console.WriteLine("Token: {0}, Value: {1}", reader.TokenType, reader.Value);
  else
    Console.WriteLine("Token: {0}", reader.TokenType);
}
```

This will iterate over whatever you have in your JSON object and output the `Token` and the `Value`.  In this case you will get this:

```
Token: StartObject
Token: PropertyName, Value: CPU
Token: String, Value: Intel
Token: PropertyName, Value: PSU
Token: String, Value: 500W
Token: PropertyName, Value: Drives
Token: StartArray
Token: String, Value: DVD read/writer
Token: Comment, Value: (broken)
Token: String, Value: 500 gigabyte hard drive
Token: String, Value: 200 gigabype hard drive
Token: EndArray
Token: EndObject
```